# Как проверить существование процесса в PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, процесс

Полная формулировка задачи: По расписанию выполнять сканирование текущих процессов в системе, если отсутствует процесс notepad (Блокнот), то запускать его.

Никогда не работал с PowerShell, но задача поставлена и её надо решить. Попытался сделать так:

```
IF (Get-Process notepad.exe -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
{

}
ELSE
{
    Start-Process notepad.exe
}
```

Но блокнот запускается всегда. Есть идеи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
Get-Process notepad
```

На моей машине (notepad.exe запущен):

```
PS D:\> Get-Process notepad

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
     67       7     2620       6956    88     0.03   2360 notepad

PS D:\> Get-Process notepad.exe
Get-Process : Cannot find a process with the name "notepad.exe". Verify the process name and call the cmdlet again.
At line:1 char:12
+ Get-Process <<<<  notepad.exe
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (notepad.exe:String) [Get-Process], ProcessCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoProcessFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
```

Comment: Так тоже не работает. У меня блокнот не запущен, но команда всё равно что-то находит.

    
    PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Process notepad
    
    Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName                                                                
    -------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------                                                                
         72       8     1468        532    36     0,09   5520 notepad

Comment: @Alouette: Хм, вы уверены? А что за процесс с Id = 5520?

Comment: Это что-то запредельно невразумительное. В диспетчере задач процесс с таким именем и таким PID не значится. В cmd ввёл команду taskkill /pid 5520 /f, он сделал вид, что убил этот процесс. После этого программа заработала. Как это объяснить?

Comment: Зомби-состояние процесса? Попробуйте в таких случаях вместо диспетчера задач использовать [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

Comment: Может процесс был запущен в другом explorer? И вы просто не видели его на экране или он был запущен без отображения окна.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( -not (get-process | where {$_.ProcessName -eq 'notepad'}))
{ 
   'not run. Start Running'
   Start-Process -FilePath 'c:\windows\notepad.exe'

}
else
{'Arlready exist'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
Get-Process "notepad" -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{
Start-Process -FilePath 'c:\windows\notepad.exe'
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.